# AngularJS - Loading template from file and passing json data into scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm brand new to angularjs and want to switch my web application to using it. I have successfully switched parts of my application but I got stuck loading html and passing my event object to it. I currently use the Handlebarjs and JQuery to build the html.

How do I switch this over to using the angular framework?

The `events` object is retrieved by calling a REST API and passed to the `loadTemplate` function.

```
var loadTemplate = function(templateType, events) {
        return Q.when($.get("javascripts/templates/" + templateType + ".html"))
            .then(function(template_text) {
                var templateContext = {
                    events: events
                };
                var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template_text);
                return $(".container").html(theTemplate(templateContext));      
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to load template files. In your case it would be:

```
<div ng-include="{{templateUrl}}"></div>
```

The `templateUrl` would be a scope variable that you'd construct as:

```
$scope.templateUrl = "javascripts/templates/" + templateType + ".html"
```

Finally, your templates will have expressions that will be evaluated and rendered.

Comment: So I should create a controller with `$scope.templateUrl = "javascripts/templates/" + templateType + ".html"`
  and pass templateType to it?